# Angular Translation Service

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-translate

I would like to translate wordings from eng to chinese using a key-value mapping approach with angular translation service but i failed. Any ideas??

mapping json:

```
"At most {{ number }} wrods":"最多輸入{{ number }}字":
```

In typescript:

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
...
this.translate = injector.get(TranslateService);
....
this.translate.instant(`At most ${50} wrods`);
```

Comment: Can this answer to your question ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59948118/i18n-translate-instant-with-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Thx for the help but i figured out the solution.

sol:

```
this.translate.instant('At most {{ number }} words.', {
                    number: 300,
                }),
```

//in mapping json

```
"At most {{ number }} words.":"最多輸入{{ number }}字。",
```

Answer (score 0):

mapping-en.json:

```
{
  "AT_MOST_X_WORDS": "At most {{ number }} words"
}
```

mapping-zh.json:

```
{
  "AT_MOST_X_WORDS": "最多輸入{{ number }}字"
}
```

```
console.log(this.translate.instant('AT_MOST_X_WORDS', {number: 50}));
// 最多輸入50字
```